# Splitting pdf files according to chapter name

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Is there anyway to split pdf file according to the chapter numbers , I am currently using ItextSharp Library and splitting according to the bookmarks which are at each chapters and then getting the page number out of that bookmark and then split according to the page.But if two chapters are on same page then it will be having two resulting pdfs each for one chapter but with same data.Can't we split according to the chapters name or number ?

Comment: _But if two chapters are on same page then it will be having two resulting pdfs each for one chapter but with same data_. Wouldn't splitting by chapter also create two pages if two chapters are on the same page? Or do you want to actually **remove** text from the extracted pages so one page only has chapter 1's text on the top and the second page only has chapter 2's text on it?

Comment: yes, I want to implement that one page should be having atmost on chapter only, as after splitting we may have to merge them, so it would be bad if two pdf file are having same data.